# How to control where cppcheck stores analyzerinfo files?

Tags: cppcheck

Recently, newer versions of `cppcheck` (2.8.2) are create files ending with `.analyzerinfo` for every source file in my repository.

So `example.c` would have a file created called `example.c.analyzerinfo`.

Is there a way to control where these files are stored?

The `--cppcheck-build-dir` is set and populated with files but the analyzerinfo files are still created in my source directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's a recent bug, as mentioned [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/development/thread/93b085f970/?limit=25). It hasn't yet been fixed since the offending commit.